# how to access request object in Sym2 FOSUserBundle custom UserChecker

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am using Synfony2 with FOSUserBundle and I have a custom userChecker where I want to validate the host of the user (we have several hosts pointing to the same IP). My problem is that inside my custom userChecker I can't access REQUEST, thus not the HOST of the request.

This is my user checker code

```
/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

//Override by Mattias

namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Controller;
//namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\LockedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountExpiredException;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker as OriginalUserChecker;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as Request; //ADDED BY MW

/**
 * UserChecker checks the user account flags.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class UserCheckerNew extends OriginalUserChecker
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
/*
        //Test for companylock...
        if ( !$user->getCompany()->getActive() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The company of this user is locked.', $user);
        }

        if ( $user->getLocked() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The admin of this company has locked this user.', $user);
        }
*/

        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException('User credentials have expired.', $user);
        }



    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {

        //Test for companylock...
        if ( !$user->getCompany()->getActive() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The company of this user is locked.');
        }    

        if ( $user->getLocked() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The admin of this company has locked this user.');
        }

/*
Validate HOST here
*/

        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
            throw new LockedException('User account is locked.', $user);
        }

        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException('User account is disabled.', $user);
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
            throw new AccountExpiredException('User account has expired.', $user);
        }
    }
}
```

In the checkPostAuth function I tried different things like passing the request

```
public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user, Request $request)
```

Error saying my override must conform to the original/interface.

Trying to get the request as in a controller

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

or like this

```
$currentHost = $request->getHost();
```

or like this

```
$cont = $this->getContainer();
```

or like this

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

or like this

```
$request = $container->get('request');
```

Yet no luck =) I'm no Symfony2 guru, as you can tell, I'm shooting from the hip here =)

---

Added parameters to config.yml according to gp-sflover's answer, my config.yml now looks like this:

```
services:
    security.user_checker:
        class: BizTV\UserBundle\Controller\UserCheckerNew
        arguments: [ "@request" ]
        scope: request
        public: true
```

The error delivered before scope:request was added to the config was:

```
Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "security.user_checker" references the service "request" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "security.user_checker" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "request" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.'
```

When adding scope: request a very similar error is returned

```
Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "security.authentication.provider.dao.main" references the service "security.user_checker" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "security.authentication.provider.dao.main" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "security.user_checker" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error
```

Adding public: true doesn't seem to make a difference. Also, I don't know what this public stuff really means, perhaps a security issue? The word public is always scary =)

Comment: just as an idea: Could you write an service which returns the Request obj that you could call from the UserChecker?

Comment: I never used "FosUserBundle" but I think you can override the `security.user_checker` service to inject the `request_stack` as argument and then retrieve it in the "Constructor" of your "UserChecker" Class (that have to implement the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extend the "OriginalUserChecker" class you can override the `security.user_checker` service to be able to inject the `request_stack` as argument and then retrieve it in your `UserChecker` class like this simple example:

**service.xml**

```
// Symfony >=2.6

<service id="security.user_checker"
         class="Your\Bundle\Path\ToYour\UserCheckerClass">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
</service>

// Symfony <2.6

<service id="security.user_checker"
         class="Your\Bundle\Path\ToYour\UserCheckerClass">
    <argument type="service" id="request" public="true" scope="request"/>
</service>
```

**UserCheckerClass**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
// Symfony >=2.6
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
// Symfony <2.6
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        // Symfony >=2.6
        RequestStack $request
        // Symfony <2.6
        Request $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // your checks here
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // your checks here
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: 'The service "security.user_checker" has a dependency on a non-existent service "request_stack".'
I am using symfony 2.3, perhaps this method is for a later version? Is the request_stack service called something else back in 2.3?

Comment: Yes for Symfony 2.3 is `request` the name of the service and the class name is `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`. Let me know.

Comment: 'Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "security.user_checker" references the service "request" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "security.user_checker" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "request" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.

Comment: I never used the 2.3 version of Symfony but if you read from the Cookbook: [How to work with scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-synchronized-service) then you can adapt the service to avoid the alert you facing. (i think you will need to add `scope="request"` to the service under "class" indication). Let me know.

Comment: @MattWelander I updated my answer with the correct service parameters :-)

Comment: Public seems to make no difference. When adding scope: request I get a similar error: Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "security.authentication.provider.dao.main" references the service "security.user_checker" which belongs to a narrower scope

Comment: I added my config to original question. I am using YML but I believe I have translated your XML correctly.

Comment: If you read the docs from my link in my previous comment **How to work with scopes** you can see that your yaml configuration is WRONG! Remove `id: "request"`.  PS: `public=true` means that you can call the service where you want inside your app (as example from your controller).

Comment: I removed the id but unfortunately it makes no difference, the error is the same.

Comment: Do you have some other bundle installed In addition to FosUserBundle? Anyway there are many ways to inject properly the `request`, as showed in: [using a service from a narrower scope](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#using-a-service-from-a-narrower-scope). Try to implement the recommended way for the `request` service (with a setter) but if you continue to have such a problem I strongly recommended you to upgrade to a newer Symfony's version. Let me know.

Comment: I tried the setter-suggestion in the linked article, same result. I also tried to change the scope (but that was your initial suggestion) and as you know, that only resulted in an error as well. Therefore, I tried the third suggestion in the linked article, and that is what worked. However, I understand your comment about that being bad practice in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I never did get the request injection to work. I did however get an injection of the entire service container to work.

This is how I ended up doing it, with guidance from [gp_sflover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3695819/gp-sflover) (if you post an answer with this code I will check yours as the correct answer, I don't want to steal cred, just get the truth out there ;] )

```
services:
    security.user_checker:
        #class: BizTV\UserBundle\Controller\UserChecker
        class: BizTV\UserBundle\Controller\UserCheckerNew
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

```
namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\LockedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountExpiredException;


class UserCheckerNew implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {

        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException('User credentials have expired.', $user);
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {

//Validate HOST here, make it look as though account doesn't exist if on wrong host
        $host = $this->container->get('request')->getHost();

        if ($host != "localhost") { //bypass all checks when on localhost

            $brandedHost = $user->getCompany()->getBrandedHost();

            if ( $brandedHost == "" ) { //if unset assume main
                $brandedHost = "login.mydomain.se";
            }

            if ( $host != $brandedHost ) {
                throw new LockedException('Invalid username or password.'); //dot added for debug
            }
        }
// end of host validation

        //Test for companylock...
        if ( !$user->getCompany()->getActive() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The company of this user is locked.');
        }    

        if ( $user->getLocked() ) {
            throw new LockedException('The admin of this company has locked this user.');
        }

        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
            throw new LockedException('User account is locked.', $user);
        }

        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException('User account is disabled.', $user);
        }

        if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
            throw new AccountExpiredException('User account has expired.', $user);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I hope there aren't any security issues about injecting the service container into the user checker...

Comment: Inject the entire service container in a service is a very bad practice for many reasons (I don't want to buy a car to use only a screw of it :-)). I will not add this code to my answer because is not the right solution (but only a dirty workaround). As said in my last  comment (without a reply), you probably have something somewhere that doesn't allow you to inject the request in the way as described (and recommended) in the Symfony's docs.

Comment: probably, but I am apparently not man enough to find it. I understand that this is not the ideal answer, but it is the only way I found to make it work. Perhaps it will work differently once I get around to updating, but from my inxperience, upgrading symfony is no small job, moving from 2.0 to 2.3 was a nightmare, took me a little under a week...